# Barracuda 340 upload ssl license automatically

Tags: ssl-certificate, upload, barracuda

I am looking for options to see whether it is possible to automate the process of SSL license upgrades with Barracuda model 340 load balancers.

I am wondering, if there is a way to upload SSL licenses automatically to Barracuda 340? Something like an interface that we can communicate programatically and upload the SSL certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this is an old question, but I am adding this answer for anyone else who is looking for information about how to use the REST API to upload certificates to a Barracuda Load Balancer ADC.

> To upload a signed certificate in PEM or PKCS #12 format, make a POST request to the following URI:
> /certificates?upload=signed

https://campus.barracuda.com/product/loadbalanceradc/doc/42049757/barracuda-load-balancer-adc-rest-api/

https://campus.barracuda.com/product/loadbalanceradc/download/12HZ/barracuda-load-balancer-adc-rest-api-v2/

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved to an extent using REST API on the  Barracuda 340 ADC

Comment: Please don't provide link only answers.

Comment: Well...I was more after putting the essentials of the link into your answer...

Comment: https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @KaushikT thanks for you comment, although this is very generic answer. Is there any documentation for REST API in Barracuda 340 ADC?